# Terminal: unknown0025003f3355:~ pontuspersson$

Tags: terminal

When I open my terminal window I get this:

```
unknown0025003f3355:~ pontuspersson$
```

Why is this? And How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your system hasn't been given a proper hostname, or has been given the hostname "unknown0025003f3355". Give it a hostname of your preference.

Comment: How do you set the host name?

Comment: @SimonSheehan Depends on the OS which the user doesn't mention.

Comment: Well let's assume it's Linux, based on how this terminal is setup. Could you provide ways for that?

Comment: @Simon: Which one?